# Limit the number of requests Nginx + uWSGI + Flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am trying to limit the number of requests per second for a flask application with uWSGi + Nginx. I need to do this in order to maintain the response time of my app below a specific threshold that I had determined.

I would like to set the rate to 4 requests per second using this nginx.config file:

```
http {
        limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=4r/s;  
        server {
            location /api/ {
                limit_req zone=mylimit burst=5 nodelay
            }
        }
}
```

But it seems that this config does not set the limit for the service itself, but for each (uWSGI) process.
Is that correct?

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: `burst` and `nodelay` options can show somewhat different behaviour other than the simple `4r/s`, have you tried to remove them and check the basic behaviour? does the actual `r/s` number correspond to the `number of processes X 4`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply:
I tried without the burst/no delay options. And it doesn't help. The actual `r/s` (between 7 and 10) doesn't equal `number of processes` (14) X 4

Comment: you can try to pinpoint the issue by creating a directive to expose a simple static html page (nginx served) and see if you get the desired request limit...